# Its seems that I have lost permissions to home folder now after rebooting I can't log in?

Tags: permissions

I have lost all permission to my he folder

/home/user

I have tried `chmod` , `chown` with no success it just doesn't change those permissions

Logging in with console mode

It says

`No directory, logging in with HOME=/`

Home folder still exist as well as the content .

Edit

After executing 
`chmod 0755 /home/user` I was able to access my `home/user` folder but I only have read permissions to its content

Comment: Please check and add to your question whether your home folder and its contents are still there. You should be able to do this without a live session. Please also add whether your home folder is encrypted or is on a dedicated partition. Furthermore, please add the output of `ls -la /home`(not in a live session) to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is fixed with this commands:

```
chmod -R u=rwX,go=rX /home/user
```

However I'm not sure if those are the right permissions for the user home folder. frankly it's mostly likely that they are not.